# How to assertThat something is null with Hamcrest?

Tags: java, assert, hamcrest

How would I `assertThat` something is `null`?

for example

```
 assertThat(attr.getValue(), is(""));
```

But I get an error saying that I cannot have `null` in `is(null)`.

Answer (score 294, accepted):

You can use [`IsNull.nullValue()`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/hamcrest/core/IsNull.html#nullValue()) method:

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.nullValue;

assertThat(attr.getValue(), is(nullValue()));
```

Comment: it says method nullValue() is not defined

Comment: @user2811419. You need to import `IsNull` It's a static method in that class. Just do `static import`, or use `IsNull.nullValue()`.

Comment: Add `import static org.hamcrest.core.IsNull.nullValue;` to your class.

Comment: In newer versions of Hamcrest the namespace has changed and you need `import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.nullValue`.

Answer (score 35):

why not use `assertNull(object)` / `assertNotNull(object)` ?

Comment: +1  I generally prefer Hamscrest assertions but this is one case where the Junit assertion is just more readable, IMO.

Comment: assertThat() give much better logging that many of the other assert* methods. The test-coding standard that I use favors assertThat() over all other assertion methods for this reason.

Comment: The main advantage when using assertThat vs assertNul is that it is closer to an Englsih spoken phrase, just try to read any of your assertions to check it up.

Comment: Using an errorCollector is a good reason to use the hamcrest matchers opposed to the assertNull/assertNotNull.

Answer (score 17):

If you want to `hamcrest`, you can do

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.nullValue;

assertThat(attr.getValue(), is(nullValue()));
```

In `Junit` you can do

```
import static junit.framework.Assert.assertNull;
assertNull(object);
```

Answer (score 12):

Use the following (from Hamcrest):

```
assertThat(attr.getValue(), is(nullValue()));
```

In Kotlin `is` is reserved so use:

```
assertThat(attr.getValue(), `is`(nullValue()));
```

Comment: Is there an alternative where we don't have to escape the `is`?

Comment: @VIN Probably if you use a fully qualified name instead of a static import?