# testing if a JSON property is null in a Spring Boot integration test

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, integration-testing

In a Spring Boot integration test, I'm trying to test if a JSON property is null

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class IntegrationTests {

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webClient;

    @Test
    void saveExtension() {
        webClient.get()
            .uri("/api/endpoint")
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus()
            .is2xxSuccessful();
            .expectBody()
            .jsonPath("$.data[0].extended").isEqualTo(null)
    }
}
```

The test passes, but I get a SpotBugs error (and an IntelliJ warning) because the parameter of `isEqualTo` is annotated `@NotNull`.

Surely there's a more elegant way of testing whether a JSON property is null? I've tried both of the following alternatives provided by `org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.JsonPathAssertions`:

- `.jsonPath("$.data[0].extended").doesNotExist()`
- `.jsonPath("$.data[0].extended").isEmpty()`

But the test fails in both cases. Is there a better way of testing if a JSON property is null?

I also tried the following:

```java
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.nullValue;
// ...
.jsonPath("$.data[?(@.bidderId == '%s')].extended", BIDDER_ID_2).value(is(nullValue()));
```

But this fails with the error:

> Expected: is null but: was <[null]>

This error message suggests that `extended: [null]` was returned but I've checked the response and it's `extended: null`

Comment: Could you use `.value` then pass a matcher for null (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/18987692/3001761)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for the suggestion - please see my update.

Comment: At that point I think you're asking https://stackoverflow.com/q/49851158/3001761 - your query returns an array of one null.